# What are the privilege required for .Net Entity Framework with Mysql 8.0.20?

Tags: mysql, .net, entity-framework, entity

I am facing a error for .Net Entity framework with MySQL 8.0.20 (MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore)

> Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on Null values.

When I give privilege to application user:

```
*GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, EXECUTE ON `database_name`.* TO `user`@`%`;*
```

it does not work(it give error as null). but when give "Select on All database privilege Provided to the application" it works.,

```
*GRANT select  ON `database_name`.* TO `user`@`%`;*
```

Comment: And the question is ?  Also "it works", what will work ?  Please add the .NET code you are talking about, and the real problem, because ending the question with "it works" will not make a very good question..... 

Comment: What is "Entity framework 8.0.20"?